# Push уведомления, FCM, и backend

Tags: android, backend, fcm, android-push-notification

Всех приветствую!
Подскажите пожалуйста как лучше сделать, или укажите направление куда двигаться в такой задаче.

Я использую Firebase realtime database в своем приложении. Логика приложения такая, что два юзера могут взаимодействовать с одними данными, то есть изменять, удалять, добавлять и тд. Задача заключается в том, что бы юзер у которого приложение закрыто, получал push notification о изменении данных другим юзером.
Как это сделать?

Создать service и в нем слушать базу? Или нужно писать свой сервер для этого?
Читал еще что пишут сервер с использованием FCM. FCM сам никогда не использовал.

Как быть?

Comment: Для внесения ясности в терминологию. `push notification` инициируется бэкендом и доставляется клиенту. То что вы описываете как "создать service и в нем слушать базу" ничего общего с `push` технологией не имеет. Это самые обычные `local notification`.

Comment: "Или нужно писать свой сервер для этого?" - да, для `push` нужен свой сервер, который собственно и будет "пушить" сообщения.

Comment: Суть вопроса в том, как оповестить пользователя о изменении в базе, если приложение закрыто.

Answer (score 1):

Да `FCM`. На ум приходит сразу несколько решений, самый простой и быстрый, это пусть юзер рассылает пуш при любом изменении своего списка в группу, которая имеет доступ к этому списку. Если на другой стороне app процесс жив, тогда Realtime Database может хендлить изменения, если нет, то придет пуш, по которому поднимайте процесс приложения.

Писать свой сервер, ну он будет relay, всё равно кому-то надо стать инициатором рассылки.

Comment: Каверзный вопрос, а как надо "поднимать" процесс приложения при приходе пуша? :)

Comment: как хотите, вы обрабатывать его будете скорей всего в FB Service, классически делают через NotificationManager, в самом билдере есть метод setContentIntent, указывают PendingIntent. В итоге будет Intent типо: 
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, LaunchActivity.class); 
ПРи нажатии на уведомление он отыграет и запустит процесс и стартанет LaunchScreenActivity

Comment: Это вы все про запуск активити, а процесс приложения то как самому "поднимать" :) В том-то и дело что никак, его система сама "поднимет" если надо. И над этим процессом разработчик невластен.

Comment: у вас очень ошибочное понимание работы процессов в ANdroid. При запуске любого компонента App запустится его процесс, если текущего не существует, эти процессы контролируется, и могут параллелиться.
Почитайте основы вот. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads?hl=ru

Comment: «Поднимать приложение» тоесть, что бы оно проверило изменения в базе? Я правильно понял?

Comment: логично) и показывать уже измененный список, можете даже обрабатывать id message и скролить до него ибо user friendly =)

Comment: Игра слов получилась, перефразирую: "В том-то и дело что никак, его система сама "поднимет" если надо. И над этой процедурой разработчик невластен."

Comment: Как быть тогда?)

Comment: А если использовать какой нибудь Alarm service, для поднятия?